# Using relative paths works for "cargo build" but not for "cargo publish"

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, rust-cargo, prost

I have a project that holds some protobuf definitions and builds code for multiple (Python and Rust) languages. The folder structure is like this:

- root/

  - proto/

    - my.proto
  - python/
  - rust/

    - Cargo.toml
    - build.rs
    - ...

I'm using [prost](https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost) to generate Rust code out of the proto files. My `build.rs` looks like this:

```
use std::io::Result;
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    prost_build::compile_protos(
        //  Files to be compiled
        &["my.proto"],
        //  Include folder for protoc
        &["../proto/"])?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This works fine if I run `cargo build`, but it does not work with `cargo publish`. In the output I see that `publish` seems to create a dedicated `package` subfolder in the `target` folder. `protoc` also tells me:

> ignoring ../proto/ since it does not exist

I wonder why this works with `build`, but not `publish`. Can somebody explain? Can it be solved or is this kind of accessing files in relative pathes a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the environment variable Cargo sets](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts):

```
use std::io::Result;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let folder_path = Path::new(std::env::var_os("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap()).join("../proto");
    prost_build::compile_protos(
        //  Files to be compiled
        &["my.proto"],
        //  Include folder for protoc
        &[folder_path],
    )?;
    Ok(())
}
```